# Numeric literals

Tags: java, literals

I was reading a book about Java and I found the following points unclear, please help me:

1. For integer literal expressed in any base other than base 10 (0b, 0, 0x) can we use the L suffix that stands for Long?
2. For floating point can we use any other base other than decimal? If yes can we specify float or double using F or D for other bases other than 10?
   If yes with other bases than 10 could we use scientific notation or only decimal point is allowed?

Comment: Why not try it out yourself?

Comment: i tried binary floating points but i had a message from the compiler : Binary literals can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater ,what does this mean

Comment: 1) we could use L with integer literals in other bases , i concluded that by trying it my self ,, but 2) we can't express floating point literal in other bases , that was the result of my exprements now ... does this seems logical for you ?? i want just to make sure of my results

Comment: Interesting question! I edited some details in it. Here is some things to think about when writing questions in the future: There's no need to include things in the title which can be understood from the tags ("
_Java_ Numeric literals"). Phrases like "thank you" in the end are not necessary. Please use proper capitalisation! There is more information about how to write questions available in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it's possible for hexadecimal, octal and binary too. See [jls-3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

2) Yes, you can use hexadecimal notation, but you are restricted to *binary exponents* and specifying the exponent is **required**. See [jls-3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

Examples:

```
0xFF.Ap0d
0xFF.1p0f
0xFF.Ap1d
0xFF.Ap-1f
0xFF.Ap-1
0x.1p16
```

If you print these literals using `System.out.println`, you get:

```
255.625
255.0625
511.25
127.8125
63.90625
4096.0
```

The meaning of the binary exponent is as follows:

The value in front of the `p` or `P` is multipled by `2^z` where `z` is the integer after the `p` (or `P`). The integer is in *decimal* format. E.g. `0xFF.1Ap0101d` stands for `255.1015625 * 2^101`.

Comment: thanks but I don't understand the binary exponent part in 2) ..... , BinaryExponent:
BinaryExponentIndicator SignedInteger     the SignedInteger here refers to what digits 0,1 only ?? we can write for example 0xFF.1Ap0101d

Comment: @Eng_Boody: I edited my answer. `SignedInteger` is in decimal format. "binary" means *base 2* in this case.

Comment: you mean 0xFF.1Ap0101d stands for 255.26 * 2^101 ?? not 255.635*2^101 ??

Comment: @Eng_Boody: Whoops, I forgot to take the 1 after the dot into account.